# Transform differents dates format to one format - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, date-format, to-date

I have a column with two date format :

1. DD/MM/YYYY
2. YYYY-MM-DD

I want to transform all date format of this column to only one date format, it is 'DD/MM/YYYY'

How can i do it in Oracle SQL ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: DO NOT store dates as strings. Use an appropriate DATE / TIME data type.  You will format dates any way you want in UI layer.

Answer (score 2):

**NEVER** store dates as strings; always use a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type.

---

From Oracle 12, you can use multiple calls to the `TO_DATE` function with different format models and use `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR` to prevent errors being raised and `COALESCE` them to find the match:

```sql
SELECT date_string_column,
       COALESCE(
         TO_DATE(
           date_string_column DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
           'fxDD/MM/YYYY'
         ),
         TO_DATE(
           date_string_column DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
           'fxYYYY-MM-DD'
         )
       ) AS date_value
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (date_string_column) AS
SELECT '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '31/12/2022' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | DATE_STRING_COLUMN | DATE_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
> | 31/12/2022 | 2022-12-31 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d98cb785948aaa9365240a3f67687752)*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only have those 2 formats, you can do something like:

```
select (case when instr(columnName, '/') > 1 then 
             to_date(columnName, 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
        else to_date(columnName, 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
        end) field_as_date 
 from tableName;
```

This should give you columnName as a Date (without the time part ofc).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way.

String data is horrible for storing anything important.  According to one of the database I work with, there are over 4000 counties in Washington State.  There are also about 15 ways to spell "3M".  You'll probably also need to find ways to cleanse your data or handle non-date data in that column.

```
with dt (dt) as (
  select cast('2021-01-31' as varchar2(50))
  from dual
  union select cast('31/01/2021' as varchar2(50))
  from dual
)

select 
  dt
, to_date(
    regexp_replace(
      regexp_replace(
        dt
        , '([[:digit:]]{2})/([[:digit:]]{2})/([[:digit:]]{4})'
        , '\3-\2-\1'
      )
      , '([[:digit:]]{4})-([[:digit:]]{2})-([[:digit:]]{2})'
      , '\1-\2-\3'
    )
    , 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  ) "dt"
from dt;
```